# Parameterized hexagonal spiral equation(s)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, curves, parametric, parametrization

I need to design a fully parameterized hexagonal spiral, where I can choose/change the distance between turns, the inner and outer radii etc. I understand that it will be somehow related to the Archimedean spiral, whose equations are $x=rcos(\theta)$ and $y=rsin(\theta)$, and I understand that it will also be linked to the $\pi/3$ value, since each internal angle of a hexagon measures 60 degrees, but I can't pull this out.

Can anyone help me with this? It would be something like the picture below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: So a spiral on a hexagonal prism instead of on  a circular prism (cylinder)?

Comment: Hi @Narasimham, yes, I have just edited the question with a picture of it!

Comment: The curve doesn't look differentiable, so don't expect a 'clean' combination of $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$.

Comment: @Servaes In particular there are five singular points for each revolution.

Comment: @augcarv You can expect a smooth parametrisation only for each $1/6$th of a turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a parametric equation for a $n$-gon spiral (thus set $n=6$ in your case): 
$$
x=\cos\left({2\pi\lfloor t\rfloor\over n}\right)k\lfloor t\rfloor(1-(t\bmod 1))
+\cos\left({2\pi(\lfloor t\rfloor+1)\over n}\right)k(\lfloor t\rfloor+1)(t\bmod 1)\\
{\ }\\
y=\sin\left({2\pi\lfloor t\rfloor\over n}\right)k\lfloor t\rfloor(1-(t\bmod 1))
+\sin\left({2\pi(\lfloor t\rfloor+1)\over n}\right)k(\lfloor t\rfloor+1)(t\bmod 1)\\
$$
As usual, $\lfloor t\rfloor$ is the floor of $t$ (greatest integer lower than $t$) and $(t\bmod 1)$ is the fractional part of $t$ (that is $t-\lfloor t\rfloor$).
Variable $k$ controls the space between turns and every unit of parameter $t$ corresponds to a side of the spiral. The logic should be clear: that's nothing else than a sequence of segments, joining points 
$P_i=ki\big(\cos{2\pi i\over n},\sin{2\pi i\over n}\big)$,
that is those points on an Archimedean spiral which are separated by a central angle of $2\pi/n$.

The spirals in figure below were obtained for $k=1$ and $0\le t\le12$ (small spiral) or $5\le t\le42$ (large spiral).

[image]

EDIT.

If one needs the spiral to have parallel sides, then one can construct it starting with a first side of length $1$ and at each step construct the following side by rotating the previous side by $\pi/3$ and prolonging then the result by a fixed amount, which we can choose as equal to $1$.

If we use the complex representation of points in the plane, then the vertices of this spiral are given by
$$
P_n=\sum_{k=0}^n kz^{k-1}=\frac{n z^{n+1}-(n+1)z^n+1}{(z-1)^2},
$$
where $z=e^{i\pi/3}$ (set $z=e^{2i\pi/n}$ for a more general $n$-gonal spiral). Switching to real coordinates $(x_n,y_n)$ this can be written as
$$
x_{n}=
+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} (n+1) \sin \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)
-\frac{1}{2} (n-1) \cos \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)
-\frac{1}{2},\\
y_{n}=
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} (n+1) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)
-\frac{1}{2} (n-1) \sin \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)
+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$
As in the previous case we can then write the parametric equation for the spiral as a sequence of line segments joining those points:
$$
x=k x_{\lfloor t\rfloor}(1-(t\bmod 1))+k x_{\lfloor t\rfloor+1}(t\bmod 1)\\
y=k y_{\lfloor t\rfloor}(1-(t\bmod 1))+k y_{\lfloor t\rfloor+1}(t\bmod 1)\\
$$
As before, parameter $k$ controls the spacing: parallel sides are distant $3k\sqrt3$ between them. The following figure was obtained with $k=1$ and $0\le t\le20$:

[image]

Comment: Fascinating, but your drawing is a little bit different from the OP. His figure looks more an involute than a spiral (the corresponding segments in it are parallel).

Comment: @RicardoCruz I know, but it isn't clear what the OP really wants.

Comment: Hi @Aretino, thanks! This will do. I will only now need to calculate the length of this geometry. Shall I simply integrate over the curve?

Comment: Yes, in principle. But it's more convenient to note that the length of the side from $t=i$ to $t=i+1$ (for integer $i$) is given by $\sqrt{4i(i+1)\sin^2(\pi/n)+1}$. And if $t$ is not integer just add the fractional part of the corresponding side.

Comment: Hi @Aretino, thanks once more. If instead of the spiral I want the "involute" (not sure what it is) as posted in my original question, i.e. a spiralled hexagon channel whose sides are exactly parallel to each other, what would be the procedure? I'd need to also be able to define the total length of the channel and the spacing between curves. Is that possible?Thanks once more for your help.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: Discretization  so  nice !!