# Parametric curve of a spiral with straight and semicircular parts

Tags: geometry, parametric

I need to design a fully parameterized spiral like this

[image]

where I can choose/change the central part length and the radius of the innermost curve.

I understand that it will be somehow related to the Archimedean spiral, whose equations are $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, but I can't pull this out.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Priyank, try to elaborate your problem, what part are you facing problem in?

Comment: By the way, Archimedes's spiral is defined by the polar equation $r = \theta;$ what you have written is just the standard change of coordinates from polar to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I need to design this spiral in a modelling software. I need to come up with a parametric equation , like x= f1(k,t) and y=f2(k,t), Variable k controls the space between turns and  t corresponds to length of straight part. This problem is similar to the follwing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338878/parameterized-hexagonal-spiral-equations

Comment: If you want to parametrize the curve from the picture, you will need to use a combination of lines and semicircles. Ultimately, your parametrization will be piecewise with 11 separate equations.

Comment: Hi Carlo, If I have 100s of concentric curves like that, do I need 100s of equations? The example i have added in the link 2 comments back, has only one equation and there you only need to specify the number of layers.

Comment: @PriyankGupta, the difference is that each smooth piece of the curve in the problem you reference is a line; however, we are dealing with a curve that consists of line segments and semicircles. Using the floor function is clever; perhaps there is a way you could implement that here to control the line segments and the semicircles. Ultimately, I think that you could get away with two equations, but the most obvious approach is to do $i$ equations for $i$ curves (regardless of its efficiency).

Comment: @ Priyank Gupta: One way of looking at it is as an archimedean spiral with delay function in the central parts.

Comment: Your curve is highly "artificial", interleaving linear and circular parts, so the parameterization will likewise need to be designed piecewise; [@Carlo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3697137/409) looks promising. ... It could be important to know: What's the purpose of this? Are you looking to, say, compute the figure as simply a static, displayed design? Or do you want to "draw" this curve in real time, at some constant speed, perhaps as the path of a moving character in a video game? The latter requires the parameterization to be "aware" of arc-length in a way the former doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Our aim is to find two curves $\mathbf l(t, k)$ and $\mathbf s(t, k)$ that depend on $t$ and an integer $k \geq 1$ such that $\mathbf l(t, k)$ gives the $k$th line segment in the curve and $\mathbf s(t, k)$ gives the $k$th semicircle in the curve. Henceforth, I will assume without loss of generality that this curve is symmetric about the $x$-axis.

Observe that we can parametrize each of the semicircles by $\mathbf s(t, k) = \langle C(k) + R(k) (-1)^{k + 1} \sin t, R(k) \cos t \rangle$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi,$ where $C(k)$ is the $x$-coordinate of the center of the $k$th semicircle, and $R(k)$ is the radius of the $k$th semicircle. Each of these curves unravels clockwise from top to bottom for $k$ odd or bottom to top for $k$ even, as desired. Considering the diagram, we have that $\{C(k)\}_{k \geq 1} = \{5, -5, 5, -5, \dots \}$ so that $C(k) = (-1)^{k + 1} 5.$ Likewise, we have that $\{R(k)\}_{k \geq 1} = \{\frac 2 2, \frac 3 2, \frac 4 2, \frac 5 2, \dots\}$ so that $R(k) = \frac{k + 1}{2}.$ We conclude therefore that the parametrization of the $k$th semicircle of the curve is given by $$\mathbf s(t, k) = \biggl \langle (-1)^{k + 1} \biggl( 5 + \frac{k + 1}{2} \sin t \biggr), \frac{k + 1}{2} \cos t \biggr \rangle \text{ for } 0 \leq t \leq \pi.$$

Observe that the sequence of $y$-coordinates for the line segments is $\{1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, \dots\}.$ Consequently, the $y$-coordinate for the line segments is controlled by the equation $y(k) = (-1)^{k + 1} \lfloor \frac{k + 1}{2} \rfloor,$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the usual floor function. Each of the line segments has length 10 (except for the first one) and has endpoints $(-5, y(k))$ and $(5, y(k)),$ so we have that $x(k) = (-1)^{k + 1} \bigl(\frac{10}{\pi} t - 5 \bigr).$ (We need to divide by $\pi$ because we assume in the parametrization of the semicircles that $0 \leq t \leq \pi.$) Consequently, we obtain $$\mathbf l(t, k) = \begin{cases} \bigl \langle (-1)^{k + 1} \bigl(\frac{10}{\pi} t - 5 \bigr), (-1)^{k + 1} \bigl \lfloor \frac{k + 1}{2} \bigr \rfloor \bigr \rangle \text{ for } \frac{\pi}{2} \leq t \leq \pi & \text{if } k = 1 \text{ and} \\ \\ \bigl \langle (-1)^{k + 1} \bigl(\frac{10}{\pi} t - 5 \bigr), (-1)^{k + 1} \bigl \lfloor \frac{k + 1}{2} \bigr \rfloor \bigr \rangle \text{ for } 0 \leq t \leq \pi & \text{if } k \geq 2. \end{cases}$$